# How can I iterate subranges in a "cyclic array"?

Tags: arrays, perl, range, cycle

I'm trying to write the following Perl subroutine. Given are an array `a` of length `n`, an index `i` in the array (`0<=i<n` an upstream window length `u` and a downstream window length `d`.

I want to iterate over the values in the upstream window and the downstream window to `i`. In the simplest case, this will iterating over the values in `a[i-u..i-1]` (upstream window) and `a[i+1..i+d]` (downstream window).

For example:  if my array is `1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10`, `i=5` and both window sizes are `2`, the upstream values are simply `6 7` and the downstream values are `9 10`.

However, there are two complications:

1. I would like to consider my array is cyclic. If `i` is relatively small (close to
   0) or large (close to `n`), then one
   of the windows may not fit in the
   array. In that case, I want to look
   at the array as a cyclic one. for
   example, if my array is `1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10`, `i=8` and both window sizes
   are `4`, the upstream values are
   simply `4 5 6 7`, but the downstream
   values are `9 10 1 2`.
2. I would prefer some way to iterate
   over these values without explicitly
   copying them into a new array, since
   they might be very long.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can just get a list of indices using the range operator (`..`) by subtracting the upstream window from `$i` and adding the downstream window to `$i`.  You will need to remember to skip the iterator when the iterator is equal to `$i` if you don't want that `$i`th value.

You will need to use the modulo operator (`%`) to keep the index within the bounds of the array.  Given an array of size `11`, we can see that by modifying the index with `11` it will always point to the right place in the array:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

for my $i (-22 .. 22) {
    print "$i => ", $i % 11, "\n";
}
```

You may run into problems with huge numbers (i.e., numbers larger than what your platform holds in an unsigned integer), because Perl 5 changes the algorithm the modulus uses around there.  It becomes more like C's `fmod` (but there are some differences).

You may also want to not use the [`integer`](http://perldoc.perl.org/integer.html) pragma.  It makes `%` faster, but you get the behavior of the C modulo operator.  Neither ANSI nor ISO define what C should do with negative numbers, so you may or may not get a valid index back.  Of course, so long as the version of C spits back either

```
X   -5 -4 -3 -2 -1 0 1
X%5  0 -4 -3 -2 -1 0 1
```

or

```
X   -5 -4 -3 -2 -1 0 1
X%5  0  1  2  3  4 0 1
```

it should be fine (if not very portable).

It looks like [C99 defines the modulo operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3609572) to return the second case, so long as `perl` gets compiled with a [C99](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C99) compiler (with the C99 flag on) it should be safe to use the `integer` pragma.

Comment: this takes care of "out of lower bound", but what about the "upper bound" (as in my example - I will try read `a[10]`, `a[11]` etc. where `length(a)==10`.

Comment: @David B Yeah, I missed that case.  The fix is to use `%`, and it makes the negative indexing irrelevant as well.