# Does either ANSI C or ISO C specify what -5 % 10 should be?

Tags: c, c99, modulo, c89

I seem to remember that ANSI C didn't specify what value should be returned when either operand of a modulo operator is negative (just that it should be consistent).  Did it get specified later, or was it always specified and I am remembering incorrectly?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Modulo operation with negative numbers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11720656/modulo-operation-with-negative-numbers)

Answer (score 40, accepted):

C89, not totally (§3.3.5/6). It can be either -5 or 5, because -5 / 10 can return 0 or -1 (`%` is defined in terms of a linear equation involving `/`, `*` and `+`):

> When integers are divided and the division is inexact, if both operands are positive the result of the `/` operator is the largest integer less than the algebraic quotient and the result of the `%` operator is positive.  **If either operand is negative**, whether the result of the `/` operator is the largest integer less than the algebraic quotient or the smallest integer greater than the algebraic quotient is **implementation-defined**, as is the sign of the result of the `%` operator.  If the quotient `a/b` is representable, the expression `(a/b)*b + a%b` shall equal `a`.

C99, yes (§6.5.5/6), the result must be -5:

> When integers are divided, the result of the `/` operator is the algebraic quotient with any fractional part discarded.<sup>88)</sup> If the quotient `a/b` is representable, the expression `(a/b)*b + a%b` shall equal `a`.
>
> <sub>88) This is often called "truncation toward zero".</sub>

---

Similarly, in C++98 the result is implementation defined (§5.6/4), following C89's definition, but mentions that the round-towards-zero rule is preferred,

> ... If both operands are nonnegative then the remainder is nonnegative; if not, the sign of the remainder is implementation-defined<sup>74)</sup>.
>
> <sub><sup>74)</sup> According to work underway toward the revision of ISO C, the preferred algorithm for integer division follows the rules defined in the ISO Fortran standard, ISO/IEC 1539:1991, in which the quotient is always rounded toward zero.</sub>

and indeed it becomes the standard rule in C++0x (§5.6/4):

> ... For integral operands the `/` operator yields the algebraic quotient with any fractional part discarded;<sup>82</sup> ...
>
> <sub>82) This is often called truncation towards zero.</sub>

Answer (score 3):

To add a little detail to KennyTM's answer: If the C Standards call something *implementation defined* then that implementation is *required* to document the choice it makes. Usually this would be in the compiler or library documentation (man page, help manual, printed docs, CD booklet :-)
Any implementation claiming conformance to C89 or later *must* provide this somewhere.
Try looking for such a document. In the case of `gcc` for example, this is in the gcc-info:

> 4 C Implementation-defined behavior
>
> ---
>
> A conforming implementation of ISO C is required to document its
>   choice of behavior in each of the areas that are designated
>   "implementation defined".  The following lists all such areas, along
>   with the section numbers from the ISO/IEC 9899:1990 and ISO/IEC
>   9899:1999 standards. Some areas are only implementation-defined in one
>   version of the standard.
>
> Some choices depend on the externally determined ABI for the platform
>   (including standard character encodings) which GCC follows; these are
>   listed as "determined by ABI" below.  *Note Binary Compatibility:
>   Compatibility, and `http://gcc.gnu.org/readings.html'.  Some choices
>   are documented in the preprocessor manual.  *Note
>   Implementation-defined behavior: (cpp)Implementation-defined behavior.
>   Some choices are made by the library and operating system (or other
>   environment when compiling for a freestanding environment); refer to
>   their documentation for details.
>
> - Menu:
> - Translation implementation::
> - Environment implementation::
> - Identifiers implementation::
> - Characters implementation::
> - Integers implementation::
> - Floating point implementation::
> - Arrays and pointers implementation::
> - Hints implementation::
> - Structures unions enumerations and bit-fields implementation::
> - Qualifiers implementation::
> - Declarators implementation::
> - Statements implementation::
> - Preprocessing directives implementation::
> - Library functions implementation::
> - Architecture implementation::
> - Locale-specific behavior implementation::