# Is the behavior of % with negative operands defined in Perl 5?

Tags: perl, modulo

Until recently (i.e. C99), the behavior of the modulo operator was implementation defined in C.  Since Perl 5 is written in C, is it reliant on the behavior of the C compiler used to build it?

Answer (score 10):

No, Perl 5 defines the modulo operator in [`perlop`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Multiplicative-Operators) and even has tests to ensure it works as documented.

from perl/t/op/arith.t

```
tryeq $T++,  13 %  4, 1;
tryeq $T++, -13 %  4, 3;
tryeq $T++,  13 % -4, -3;
tryeq $T++, -13 % -4, -1;
```

However, if you use the [`integer`](http://perldoc.perl.org/integer.html) pragma, you are at the mercies of the C compiler.

Comment: It's worth adding that C99 specifies a [different, incompatible behaviour](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3609572/does-either-ansi-c-or-iso-c-specify-what-5-10-should-be).

Answer (score 2):

Perl implements its own modulo operator, but you can get to the one from your C compiler by using the [integer](http://perldoc.perl.org/integer.html) pragma. [perlop](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html) says

> Note that when use integer is in scope, "%" gives you direct access to the modulo operator as implemented by your C compiler. This operator is not as well defined for negative operands, but it will execute faster.

That is, you have to be careful when you are using [integer](http://perldoc.perl.org/integer.html) because the modulo might give you different answers.