# What C program behaves differently in run-time when compiled with C89 and C99?

Tags: c, language-lawyer, c99, c89

I found the following snippet (I think in Wikipedia) that creates a different run-time when C++ comments are recognized than when not:

```
int a = 4 //* This is a comment, but where does it end? */ 2
  ;
```

But until now that's been the only one (variants excluded).

I'm not interested in differentiating using `__STDC__` and the like, and not in programs that C89 will not compile.

Are there other programs/snippets producing a different run-time with C89 than C99?

Comment: I think the rules for types of integer literals changed slightly, so you can probably make a program where an expression has the wrong signedness and thus different behavior depending on C89 vs C99...

Comment: @R.. Any pointers to a source? I'll figure it out myself, but a pointer to a source would be helpful.

Comment: Sorry, that's why I wrote it as a comment not an answer. :-)

Comment: I think the standard committee spends a lot of effort to have backwards compatibility. I you find another than the one you cite, you  should file a defect report.

Comment: To whoever voted to close this question:  Imagine what will happen when you have to debug someone else's code, and you don't know which compiler they originally depended on.

Comment: @JamesAnderson (and two others) I don't want to be picky, but what is the necessity to keep editing my title? A feature is a property of a programming language and show behavior only when implemented. A program shows behavior since it is an implementation. Shees, three edits back and forth...

Comment: @Johan. For clarity really. The title as it stands is about particular programs, whereas, you question is about how features of the programming language are implemented differently according to different standards.

Comment: @Windowsprogrammer: You don't need to know the compiler. The example code above is a bug (unless the intent is exactly to find the difference between compilers) on any compiler, because its behaviour relies on unexpected and non-obvious behaviour, so if you encounter that kind of code, you change it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This program will print `0.000000` on a conforming C89 implementation and `1.000000` on a conforming C99 implementation:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    double d = strtod("0x1", NULL);
    printf("%f\n", d);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: +1 Wonderful! C89 stops at the `x` and converts only zero (since hex number support is new in C99), whereas C99 converts the hex number 1. Thanks, this is what I'm looking for!

Comment: @JohanBezem: Be aware that as a practical matter, pure C89 standard libraries seem to be getting thin on the ground.

Comment: I don't intend to use this in live code. And I'm in embedded, pretty ancient compilers survive there occasionally.

Answer (score 3):

Two examples:

- C99 has `-3/2` as Defined Behaviour (namely, to truncate to zero).
- C99 has `-1<<1` as Undefined Behaviour (but not C89).

Also, in the past I've run into problems with 64-bit enums, such as `enum {mask = 1ULL << 32}`, but I don't recall if the compiler was silent, or just quietly did the wrong thing.

Comment: AFAIK `long long` is not in the C89 Standard. I'll evaluate the other two examples, thanks!

Comment: even in C99 (as well as C1x), enumerations are restricted to values in range of `int`

Comment: @Christoph True, but many compilers will support some deviations like this.

Comment: @JosephQuinsey Your two examples are correct, but conforming C89 compilers may interpret the expressions identical to C99 conforming compilers AFAICT. That would make it an unreliable test, albeit it a valid one. Thanks anyway! +1

Answer (score 2):

Integer division can produce a different result, depending on which c89 implementation you used.

[Does either ANSI C or ISO C specify what -5 % 10 should be?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3609572/does-either-ansi-c-or-iso-c-specify-what-5-10-should-be)

Comment: But a C89 implementation *can* implement C99 semantics, so that's not a reliable way to distinguish.