# How to divide an odd number to leave two integers?

Tags: math

If I have an odd number, how would I divide it in two and leave two integers, with the first being one more than the second. For instance 9 would produce 5 and 4?

Comment: You mean `a / 2` and `a / 2 + 1`?

Comment: do you want the expressions to produce the correct answer if 1. the number is even (or will it never be needed?), and 2. if the number is negative?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The "smaller half" of `int x` is `x/2`. The "bigger half" is `x/2 + x%2` or `x - x/2`.

Note that "smaller" and "bigger" refer to the absolute value, so in the case of negative `x`, `bigger < smaller`.

Of course, if `x` is always odd and positive, then `x%2` will be `1` and the bigger half can also be computed as `x/2 + 1`.

Comment: `x - x/2` would be somewhat simpler for the second part, given that you just calculated `x/2` ;-)

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: good point, added it. I do believe that integer division on the x86 always produces the modulus in a register as well, so a smart compiler might optimize the `x%2` into a register access.

Comment: Unlikely that performance is that relevant and you still have to perform an addition, just as per my version.

Comment: @larsmans - integer division by 2 is a piece of cake for any decent compiler: this is just a shift right. No need of an integer `div`.

Comment: @mouviciel: "this is just a shift right" -- assuming an unsigned type. There's a little more to it for signed types because of round-towards-zero. In this example, we might know that the value will always be positive and so it doesn't matter, but if the compiler doesn't know that then it can't make that transformation even if it wants to.

Comment: @mouviciel for negative integers, `x / 2` and `x >> 1` are different

Comment: @Steve Jessop - I agree. nothing indicates that input should be unsigned.

Answer (score 5):

What about this?

```
int a = 9;
int c = a/2;
int b = a-c;
```

Comment: But if a is even, the result is not what is wanted.

Comment: @Richard Number is odd according to question.

Comment: The spec indicates that a is odd.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan the question states `If I have an odd number`. So, the results should be `x / 2` if it's an even number.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII The question states that the input is odd. Read it again.

Comment: The question I'm reading says "**If** I have an odd number..." which sounds like there is some possibility the number might be even.  Besides, why bother using a solution that works *only* for odd numbers, when a solution that also works for even numbers is just as easy?

Comment: @Brian - I read: _If I have_ as: _Given the assumption that_. There is no spec about what to do if the input does not meet the spec. Maybe it is a critical error that needs a hard reset of the board. This is definitively something to be discussed with the client and not something that can be assumed by a developer.

Comment: I read the *if I have* as a spec as well, but this will not work for a negative odd number.

Comment: @mouvicel, good point, but if failure on even numbers were part of the spec, it should be coded as a separate validation step. I like your answer as it is now because it is correct for all input, regardless of whether the spec currently considers that input to be valid.

Answer (score 3):

This would be my recommended way:

```
int low = floor(x / 2.0f);
int high = ceil(x / 2.0f);
```

I find it to be more concise than the `x/2 + x%2` version.
This version also benefits from the fact that the output will be correct if you happen to run it using an even number.

EDIT:

People seemed to complain about me using floating point for integers, well here is a completely bitwise based version:

```
int a = 9;

int b = a >> 1;
int c = b | (a & 0x1);
```

The only caveat with #2 is that if the input is negative, the results will not be what is expected.

Comment: -1 You use `floor` and `ceil` with floating point input. Your inputs are integers.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan good point, fixed, now remove your down vote!

Comment: Not if that's the best asking you can do. And not if you insist on using floating point for a problem that should be performed purely with integer arithmetic.

Comment: Integer arithmetic should not use `double` operations. What if the code is to be executed on an embedded microcontroller with no FPU and no `math.h`?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan floating point math isn't that slow these days, and not to mention the fact that the modulo operator can take quite some time to perform.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII I don't care about performance, it's just pointless to use FP math for the most trivial integer arithmetic imaginable. If I would never allow this code past code review.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan alright, I updated my answer with a completely bitwise version of the operation.

Comment: Bit twiddling is even worse! Just use proper arithmetic operators for the love of god! This is the most trivial programming problem imaginable.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan but I like bit twiddling, its fun! (and generally faster vs. the standard operators).

Comment: No, it is not faster. Not unless your compiler is rubbish.

Answer (score 3):

For the folks who use microcontrollers, where `/` and `%` are *fearsome-cost* operations :-)

This shows an alternative method, using shift `>>` and `&` which are sometimes cheaper:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    const int iplus = 9;
    const int iminus = -9;

    printf("iplus=%d iminus=%d\n", iplus, iminus);

    printf("(iplus >> 1)=%d ((iplus >> 1) + (iplus & 1))=%d\n", iplus >> 1, (iplus >> 1) + (iplus & 1));
    printf("(iminus >> 1)=%d ((iminus >> 1) + (iminus & 1))=%d\n", iminus >> 1, (iminus >> 1) + (iminus & 1));

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
iplus=9 iminus=-9
(iplus >> 1)=4 ((iplus >> 1) + (iplus & 1))=5
(iminus >> 1)=-5 ((iminus >> 1) + (iminus & 1))=-4
```

According to this [Does either ANSI C or ISO C specify what -5 % 10 should be?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3609572/does-either-ansi-c-or-iso-c-specify-what-5-10-should-be)

There is a difference of behaviour for `/` between C89 and C99, and specifically C89 `'/` with one negative number may return a positive or negative result, but C99 is negative.

Answer (score 1):

I thought the accepted answer was in the ballpark but unclear.  If you want some copy and paste code this would be the best solution in my eyes

```
var number = 11;
var halfRoundedUp = (number % 2) ? number/2 + .5 : number/2;
var halfRoundedDown = (number % 2) ? number/2 - .5 : number/2;
alert(halfRoundedUp +" "+ halfRoundedDown);
```