# why has erlang redefined something as basic as a remainder?

Tags: math, erlang

All our mathematics books have been teaching us that a remainder is always positive. Wiki tells me that a remainder can be a least positive remainder or a least absolute remainder. It is a pretty basic concept which can be very difficult to unlearn for a lot people(including me). It could be cause of weird bugs when a programmer is working with multiple languages.

What is the reason behind erlang redefining such a basic concept?

`Eshell V6.2  (abort with ^G)
1> -5 rem 3.
-2`

This result is not consistent with either of Least Positive Remainder or Least Absolute Remainder Concept.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remainder#Integer_division

Comment: Computer scientists are not mathematicians, and they both have completely different attitudes. The erlang language designers probably felt this was more pragmatic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is because integer divisions are rounded towards 0.

It happens in many other programming languages, for example see [this answer about C](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3609607/1387346).

---

Indeed if you consider the division as being defined before the `%` operation, then we still expect 
`a = (a / b) * b + (a % b)`. It then comes naturally that

- 5 / 3 = 1, so 5 % 3 == 2
- -5 / 3 = -1, so 5 % 3 == -2

If we rounded toward -infinity instead of towards 0, then -5/3 would be -2, and % would be the modulus operator. Right now it is just a remainder of the division.